# Why ab of L*a*b is divided by 110 to normalize it between -1 and 1?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, pytorch

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/colorizing-black-white-images-with-u-net-and-conditional-gan-a-tutorial-81b2df111cd8) tries to explain image colorizing strategy of pix2pix research.
This question references this article only.

In the dataset 'Making Dataset and DataLoaders' section, inside __getitem__ method, after converting the image to L*a*b, they divide L part of the tensor by 50 and subtract 1. This will surely bring the L values between -1 and 1 as L ranges from 0 to 100.

But ab values are divided by 110, which is strange, as ab values range from -128 to 128. As of my understanding, ab should be divided by 128 to bring its values between -1 and 1.

If anyone understands the logic behind this, please take the time to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoriticaly a and b are not bounded but often clamped for practical reason.

[from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space)

> The a* and b* axes are unbounded, and depending on the reference white
> they can easily exceed ±150 to cover the human gamut. Nevertheless,
> software implementations often clamp these values for practical
> reasons. For instance, if integer math is being used it is common to
> clamp a* and b* in the range of −128 to 127.

I think that the source of the 110 is [this](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eruzon/software/rgblab.html) Matlab implementation

However, I assume that this DOESN'T hold for the skimage.color implemneation so it may be a mistake.

[2](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eruzon/software/rgblab.html): [http://ai.stanford.edu/~ruzon/software/rgblab.html](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eruzon/software/rgblab.html) scikit.